# sqoop import is showing error

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I'm using hadoop 2.5.1 and sqoop 1.4.6.

I am using sqoop import for importing table from mysql database to be used with hadoop. It is showing following error

**Sqoop Command**

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/<dbname> --username hadoopsqoop --password hadoop@123 --table tablename -m 1
```

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer
```

Is there any way to figure out issue?

Comment: What version of hadoop and sqoop you are uisng? What sqoop command you have tried?

Comment: I'm using hadoop 2.5.1 and sqoop 1.4.6.

Comment: I'm using sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/<dbname> \
--username hadoopsqoop \
--password hadoop@123 \
--table tablename \
-m 1;

Comment: Have you set the HADOOP_HOME correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out issue. I set HADOOP_HOME correctly and it solves my problem.

Answer (score -1):

How can you import with out mentioning where to store the file. try this

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname --username hadoopsqoop --password hadoop@123 --table tablename --target-dir 'hdfspath' -m 1
```